# Linux: How to find out which (sub) dependency of my library needs a specific library?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dependencies, tcl, ubuntu-12.04

The title may seem complicated.

I made a library to be loaded within a Tcl script. Now I need to transfer it to **Ubuntu 12.04**.
Tclsh gives the following error:

```
couldn't load file "/apollo/applications/Linux-PORT/i586/lib/libapmntwraptcl.so":
**libgeos-3.4.2.so**: 

cannot open shared object file:  No such file or directory

while executing "load $::env(ACCLIB)/libapmntwraptcl[info sharedlibextension]"
```

The library libgeos doesn't have the version 3.4.2 under Ubuntu 12.04. So I need to know which (sub) dependency of my library needs the famous libgeos-3.4.2.so, so that I can rebuild it or find an alternative.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Thank you for your USEFUL answers. I already did ldd -v or -r. I have 200+ dependencies when I do ldd -r. The worst is, in the result list I see **libgeos-3.3.8.so => /usr/lib/libgeos-3.3.8.so (0xb3ea9000)** (version I have), but when I execute, Tclsh says 
**libgeos-3.4.2.so** missing.

That's why I need something able to tell me the complete dependency tree of my library.

Could anyone give me a hint (not some useless showoff)?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What if do `ldd -v /apollo/applications/Linux-PORT/i586/lib/libapmntwraptcl.so` and look for `not found` in the output. Also `ldd -r /apollo/applications/Linux-PORT/i586/lib/libapmntwraptcl.so` outputs missing objects or functions.

Comment: `readelf -d /path/to/libname.so | grep "Shared library"` will output direct dependencies. It may be needed to perform it on each dependency again. Don't know automated way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've accidentally (probably through no fault of your own) wandered into “DLL Hell”; the problem is that something that `libapmntwraptcl.so` depends on, *possibly indirectly*, does not have its dependencies satisfied. **This sort of thing can be very difficult to solve** precisely because the tools that know what went wrong (in particular, the system dynamic linker library) produce such little informative output by default.

What's even worse is that you have apparently multiple versions about. That's where DLL Hell reaches its worst incarnation. You need to be a detective to solve this; it's too hard to sensibly do remotely as many of the things that you poke your fingers at are determined by what previous steps said.

You need to identify exactly what versions you're loading, with `ldd libapmntwraptcl.so` (in your shell, not in Tcl). You also need to double check what your environment variables are immediately before the offending `load` command, as several of them can affect the loading process. The easiest way to do that is to put `parray env` just before the offending `load`, which will produce a dump of everything in the context where things could be failing; reading the manual page for `ld.so` will tell you a lot more about each of the possible candidates for trouble (there's many!).

You might also need to go through the list of libraries identified by the `ldd` program above and check whether each of those also has all their dependencies satisfied and in a way that you expect, and you should also bear in mind that failing to locate with `ldd` might not mean that the code actually fails. (That would be too easy.)

You can also try setting the `LD_DEBUG` environment variable to `all` before doing the `load`. That will produce quite a lot of information on standard out; maybe it will give you enough to figure out what is going wrong?

Finally, on Linux you need to bear in mind that there can be an RPATH set for a particular library (which can affect where it is found) and there's a system library cache which can also affect things.

---

I'm really sorry the error message isn't better. All I can really say is that it's exactly as much as Tcl is told about what went wrong, and its hardly anything.

Comment: I finally "solved" the problem by copying all missing dependencies from the old OS into a specific directory in the new OS. (Because Ubuntu 12.04 LTS does not always have new versions of libraries, for example I cannot install libgeos-3.4.2 without recompiling).

Thank you so much for your answer Donal :)